# "error: linker command failed with exit code" for using crypt function

Tags: c, encryption, crypt

I am trying to use `crypt` function like this (I'm new to C, this is just for learning)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>


char *crypt(const char *key, const char *salt);

int main()
{
    char* key="ilya";
    char* salt="xx";

    char* password=(char*)crypt(key, salt);

    printf("%s\n", password);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it using `make filename`
And I get the following error:

```
/home/bla/password.c:20: undefined reference to `crypt'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why is that?

(I know it is a very lousy way to encrypt things, this is just for learning purposes)

Comment: (I don't answer to your question but what do you cast the output of crypt in your main ?)

Comment: Is 'crypt' defined in the same .c file ?

Comment: Maybe follow linker advice [from this document](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/crypt.3.html) if Linux is your intended platform.

Comment: Quoth the man page "Programs using any of these functions on a glibc  2.x  system  must  be linked against libcrypt."; use `-lcrypt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `gcc file.c -o file -lcrypt` to link the libcrypt library if you're running Linux.

You can remove the `(char*)` cast from calling `crypt()`, it already returns a `char *` and also the declaration of the `crypt()` function since it's already provided from `unistd.h`.

I also suggest you change this:

```
char *key
char *salt
```

to

```
const char *key
const char *salt
```

Since they are pointing to read-only memory and will produce a `SIGSEGV` (Segmentation fault signal) if you try to modify the content they point to.